# How to return Axes objects generated by gridspec as though they were generated by plt.subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I construct several `Axes` objects using `gridspec`. I want to create an object `axs` which is a compilation of these `Axes` objects, but which I can call as though `axs` were created using `_, axs=plt.subplots(*args, **kwargs)`. I've tried making a manual list:

```
axs = [[ax1, ax2, ...], [ax3, ax4, ...]]
```

But this is a nested list and will have to be accessed using `axs[m][n]` rather than `axs[m,n]` like a subplots object would. What's the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create an array yourself, similar to the nested list:

```py
axs = np.asarray([[ax1, ax2, ...], [ax3, ax4, ...]])
```

It's not completely clear to me how you create the axes. But when you have for example your gridspec object, calling the `subplots` method should give you a similar array compared to `plt.subplots`:

```py
axs = gs.subplots()
```

It might also be worth looking at the relatively new `plt.subplot_mosaic` which allows you name the axes, basically storing them in a dict:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/provisional/mosaic.html#

Both `plt.subplots` and `plt.subplot_mosaic` also directly support the width and height ratio keywords (previously via `gridspec_kw`), so for most cases you might be able to get what you want directly with `plt.subplots`.

Comment: Exactly! With `axs = gs.subplots()` the `axs[m,n]` are `matplotlib.axes` in a numpay array and can be used for e.g. `axs_arr[0,0].plot()`.

Comment: Oh this is new to me! I construct my Axes using `ax=fig.add_subplot(gs[1,1])` . I didn't know I could call subplots directly from gridspec. Thanks!